# Doesn't all HTML tags need to be closed?

Tags: html

I see some HTML codes like `<tag attribute='x'>` without the closing `</tag>`, surprisingly in w3schools.com.

One example is here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

And I know that some tags do work without closing them, but in the long run they can result in invisible failures, and moreover, my coder instincts tell me that all tags need to be closed.

So are there some tags (or some contexts) that do not need to be closed?

Thanks !

Comment: depends if you are working to xhtml standards or not (your doctype - eg if you had a doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` you would need to close your tags), besides don't trust all you see in w3schools - http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: w3schools is fine as an introduction or quick (& dirty) reference, but it's in no way authoritative or official.

Comment: w3schools is unreliable, see http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is leaving out end tags valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130781/is-leaving-out-end-tags-valid)

Comment: Wow, until I saw w3fools.com, I was thinking that w3schools was the standard html documentation of some kind :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tags which are not containers and therefore can't be closed because they are one unit, for example the image tag:

```
<img src="abc.jpg">
```

However if you want to follow html standard, you need to write this like:

```
<img src="abc.jpg" />
```

Comment: Oh, so you must close the tags which has (or can have) children? So, do you have to close <a>'s? Since they can have children too?

Comment: Yes, you have to always close <a> tags as they are containers.

Answer (score 1):

No tags do not always have to be closed; the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) enumerates when and where this behavior is appropriate. However it is much easier for browsers to parse the HTML if tags are closed properly, IE9 does not follow the HTML5 parsing rules and may break if tags are not closed properly.